# Distribution theory and locally integrable functions

Tags: distribution-theory

A locally integrable function $f$ defines a distribution from $\mathcal{D}(U)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Why is it acceptable to say that $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ (the space of locally integrable functions) is subspace of $\mathcal{D}'(U)$ (the space of distributions over $U$)? Knowing that $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ contains functions not functionals.

Comment: there is a natural injective linear transformation of locally integrable functions (strictly speaking equivalence classes) into the space of distributions given by integration against test functions. It's because of the injection that we "identity"locally integrable functions with a certain vector subspace of distributions. So technically its an abuse of terminology to say a locally integrable function **is** a distribution. But we learn to tolerate such abuses because otherwise every sentence we speak of will get tremendously wordy.

Comment: this is kind of like how when we start with the rational numbers, and define real numbers as equivalence classes of cauchy sequences of rationals (or Dedekind cuts) then strictly speaking a rational number is NOT a real nunber. However, there is a natural subfield of the reals which we can "identify" with the rationals.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ doesn't even contain functions but equivalence classes of functions. One equivalence class contains functions that differ on sets that don't matter when it comes to integration. That said, we still think of it as a space of functions.

It's true that $f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ is not a functional *per se*, but given $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}$ we define a distribution $T_f$ by
$$\langle T_f, \varphi \rangle = \int f(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx.$$
This gives a continuous injection $f \mapsto T_f : L^1_{\text{loc}} \to \mathcal{D}'$ which is why we consider $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ to be a subspace of $\mathcal{D}'$.

Answer (score 0):

Right! I think one great virtue of L. Schwartz' idea of treating "distributions" as continuous linear functionals was that it made their *existence* completely rigorous. And some other basics.

At the same time, in general the dual space of a topological vector space does not naturally contain the original space. In the case of distributions, the possibility to view them as *generalized_functions*, enlarging the class of "functions", is/was very important. E.g., now we can differentiate a step function ... and get a Dirac delta at the jump. And there are various theorems showing that (locally, or with other hypotheses) every distribution is a sufficiently high-order derivative of a *continuous* function... And similar.

But/and, yes, we should be sure to remember that the "functional" given by an $L^1$ function is really integrate-against-it. When I teach courses introducing these ideas, a repeatedly write "(integration-against-) $L^1$ function $f$"...

There are some relatively minor normalization and/or notational complications arising from identifying $f$ with integration-against-$f$, but these are easy to accommodate.